# Shortened URL is not listed in the Linked section

Tags: bug, status-review, hyperlinks, linked-questions, sharing

Within a certain site, when I link to any question or answer for a reference, I've been using short URL's like `/q/12345` or `/a/12345`, and these are linking and redirecting correctly.

But the linked questions are not listed in the **Linked** section of the current post.

For example, in this very question I have linked to [this answer to "What does #Soreadytohelp mean?"](/a/294945) using the short URL, and as you can see it is not listed in the **Linked** section.

Is using shortened URL's recommended here or not?

Comment: Related: '[Relative links are ignored by "Linked Questions"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/120678/271271)' and '[Protocol-relative and relative URLs should be considered "Linked"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/291236/271271)'. Note that the first link here sounds very similar, but is different enough such that the fix they implemented for that question didn't resolve this one.

Comment: Possibly related on Physics Meta: [Shortened links to PSE posts generated by the "cite" feature don't seem to be added to the Linked tab (as of August 27, 2023)](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/14504/148225)